# Google Sign-In for asp.net webform with custom database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, google-api, google-signin

I have a webform application (.NET 4.5) for our company, called Employee Portal, basically every employee has a login (company's email + password). This is a custom user login (using form authentication), I don't use any of Membership or Identity whatsoever.

Recently we moved our email system to google (gmail business) so everybody basically now has a google account, of course all email addresses remain the same.

So instead of having to remember/using 2 login information for Employee Portal and Email, I am trying to implement Google sign-in for the Employee Portal webform app, so that employee now only need to remember the email/google account. The idea is simple as that: Users go to login page => login using google => google api return user's email => verify if this email existing in current database => log them in. **(But I don't know if this "idea" is a secure approach?)**

Since I've never used any kind of external API apps before, I need a good reference guild to follow, but most of the search results either returned outdated articles or MVC related ones so I am having a hard time to get started. I found this on Google: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

am I in a right place? that "starting code" above looks like it is on html page, I don't see any ".NET" guild for server side, could anyone please point me to a right direction?

Comment: did you find some solution for the web form. Would be appreciated if you can share thanks